# Re-use schema.org vocabulary and tree model in application?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm building a new application and in order to not reinvent the wheel I' d like to re-use the vocabulary and tree model proposed on Schema.org.

For eg, I' dlike to implement a crud for [Organization](https://schema.org/Organization), + create and attach an [Offer](https://schema.org/Offer) to it.

However, I'm not sure to see how to start  : 
Would it be possible to generate automatically an object model tree (java/ javascript) from a json-ld representation ?

Is there any kind of existing framework that already feed the gaps between the Schema.org models / web display / crud operation / REST api creation ?

Could you please point me to the right direction ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should have a look at https://api-platform.com/ It is a framework to build Web APIs based on JSON-LD, Schema.org and Hydra.

Comment: Woo,  thank you !  That's exactly what I was looking for on the principle. Any chance to get a similar framework written in java/scala or javascript ?

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/dschulten/hydra-java You may wanna join the Hydra W3C Community Group if this stuff interests you. We discuss and develop it there: http://www.hydra-cg.com/#community